# Kotlin function for getting start and end index of substring

Tags: android, string, kotlin, substring

I'm wondering is there some method or methods combo that could obtain these results.

What I meant is that you have a string ex. `"Hello world, how are you?"`
And I want to achieve following functionality, to get start and end index of substring
in that string.

ex. substring = "world", and start index would be 6, and end index 10

Is there something like this in standard kotlin libraries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
val s = "Hi there"
val substringToFind = "there"

val start = s.indexOf(substringToFind)
val end = start + substringToFind.length

println(s.substring(start,end))
```

output: `there`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just use **[indexOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-string-builder/index-of.html)** assuming you just want the first occurence:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val str = "Hello world, how are you?"
    val sub = "world"
    println(getStartAndEndOfSubstring(str, sub))
}

fun getStartAndEndOfSubstring(str: String, sub: String): Pair<Int, Int> {
    val start = str.indexOf(sub)
    when (start != -1) {
        true -> return Pair(start, start + sub.length - 1)
        false -> return Pair(-1, -1)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
(6, 10)
```